# Django redirect to AdminSite Views from template

Tags: django, django-admin

I have created a few custom views in admin, by subclassing AdminSite. Which is below:

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # login_template = 'screens/login.html'
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        urls += [
             path('view', self.admin_view(self.home)),
             path('details',self.admin_view(self.details)),
             path('listing',self.admin_view(self.listing)),
        ]
        
        return urls

    def home(self, request):
        return render(request, 'base.html')
    
    def details(self,request):
        return render(request, 'screens/details.html')
    
    def listing(self,request):
        return render(request, 'screens/listing.html',content)


site =  MyAdminSite()
```

In one of the html templates, i want to redirect to one of the views created above. Below is what i tried,

```
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Admin</div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a href="{% url 'admin:details' %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Edit Details</a>
  </div>
</div
```

I tried `{% url 'admin:details' %}` and `{% url 'admin/details' %}`, but im getting this error:

```
 django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'details' not found. 'details' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

My main urls.py has urlpatterns as:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the **`name`** for your urls - `path`([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path)):

```
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    # login_template = 'screens/login.html'
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        urls += [
             path('view', self.admin_view(self.home), name="home_view"),
             path('details',self.admin_view(self.details), name="screen_details"),
             path('listing',self.admin_view(self.listing), name="screen_listing"),
        ]
        
        return urls

     ...
```

You can use in template: `{% url 'admin:screen_details' %}`

In the view or another method: `reverse("admin:screen_details")`

Comment: That didn't work for me for some reason.